# How to calculate the Sum of all Values in a Ruby Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, sum

I have an array as follows:

`a = [1,2,5,8]`

I want to calculate the value of all the elements added(or multiplied) together.

Comment: For adding the elements of the array you can simply use sum method.      a.sum will give you result.

Comment: In Rails and in Ruby [since version 2.4.0](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_0/NEWS) ([released 2016-12-25](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/12/25/ruby-2-4-0-released/)) theres is `Array#sum` and `Enumerable#sum` doing just this.

Answer (score 13):

```
a.inject{ |sum,x| sum + x }
```

Or slightly shorter and faster:

```
a.inject(:+)
```

For multiplication or whatever else, just change the sign: `a.inject(:*)`

Comment: Asking and answering your own question is encouraged: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/.  But in this case there are approachingly-infinite dupes so I would say that's "less encouraged."